# youtube-dl not performing as expected on 12.10

Tags: downloads, youtube

When I type the video url, it bring out this message instead of download.

Please what do I do because I really need to start downloading videos.

```
joshua@joshua-HP-625:~$ youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3gPo7qFOFw&

feature=player_detailpage
[1] 6720
joshua@joshua-HP-625:~$ Hi! We changed distribution method and now youtube-dl needs to update itself one more time.
This will only happen once. Simply press enter to go on. Sorry for the trouble!
The new location of the binaries is https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/downloads, not the git repository.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues.

1. You need to surround your link in `"` to escape that last ampersand `&`:

   ```
   youtube-dl "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3gPo7qFOFw&"
   ```
2. You need to update *youtube-dl* one more time, run as `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo youtube-dl --update
   ```

   and press Enter when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

First, the **&** sign at the end of the link is forcing youtube-dl to run in the background.

Second, the instructions give you the location of the new download: https://github.com/downloads/rg3/youtube-dl/youtube-dl

Finally, consider a site like http://www.keepvid.net in the meantime.